# WPF - Binding nested custom objects to datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have a pretty large object and some of it's properties should be shown in a datagrid. The problem is that the binding is not doing well and the nested object values are empty.

The **MainCustomObject** is:

```
public class MainCustomObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CustomObject1 CustomObject1 { get; set; }
}
```

The **CustomObject1** is:

```
public class CustomObject1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And my **XAML** code is:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MainCustomObjectList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="75" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomObject1_Name" Width="75" Binding="{Binding CustomObject1.Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomObject1_Url" Width="75" Binding="{Binding CustomObject1.Url}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: `is not doing well` what? I mean: what's wrong with it?

Comment: The ItemsSource must be an IEnumerable. What is "ObjectList"?

Comment: And how does `CustomObject1` look like? Does it have public Id and Name properties?

Comment: @Stefan I mean it does not show the values! It's all empty

Comment: @mm8 That's just a name for the IEnumerable. Changed it to prevent the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Clemens I updated the question.

Comment: I still see no MainCustomObjectList property in your sample code...

Comment: Ok, and what exactly does it mean when you say that "*the binding is not doing well*"? Is the DataGrid empty?

Comment: @Clemens Yeah. The nested object values are empty.

Comment: *The nested object values are empty* means there are rows in the DataGrid which show the value of the Name property in the first column, but the second and third columns are empty? Please tell us precisely what's wrong.

Comment: @Clemens I mean that the _Name_ and _Id_ from `MainCustomObject` has proper values but the _Name_ and _Url_ of `CustomObject1` are empty.

Comment: Sorry, but "*proper values*" means there **are rows** in the DataGrid, as many as elements in MainCustomObjectList? Why can't you say whether there are rows or not? Yes or no?

Comment: Did you set the CustomObject1 property of the MainCustomObjects then?

Answer (score 1):

I tested you code and it works in that way, that a row is created and displayed. Your Namespace or class name might be different.

**MainWindow**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public IEnumerable<MainCustomObject> MainCustomObjectList { get; set; } = new List<MainCustomObject>
    {
        new MainCustomObject
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Name1",
            CustomObject1 = new CustomObject1
            {
                Name = "Custom name 1",
                Url = "Url 1"
            }
        }
    };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MainCustomObjectList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomObject1_Name" Binding="{Binding CustomObject1.Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomObject1_Url" Binding="{Binding CustomObject1.Url}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Note that I bound the `DataContext` to my own instance. Otherwise it would show the same error you are reporting, an empty list. You also want to make sure, that the list is completely initialized, as *mm8* suspects. If only the first column is filled, that is a hint, that the property `CustomObject1` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind the `ItemsSource` property to an `IEnumerable` (including any type that implements the `IEnumerable` interface). So your XAML markup should work provided that `MainCustomObjectList` returns an `IEnumerable<MainCustomObject>` and that the `CustomObject1` type has public `Name` and `Url` properties that are actually populated with some values.

Also make sure that `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` is an instance of the class where the `MainCustomObjectList` property is defined.

Comment: @Stefan: `IEnumerable` is an interface that you *implement*. All classes that implement this interface are indeed `IEnumerables`.

Comment: However, this [fastest-gun-in-the-west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) style post does not at all answer the question, because you couldn't wait until OP clarified the questions in the comments.

Comment: @Clemens: If it doesn't answer the question, what is the question then?

Comment: Now that you've read all the comments on the question, you know that it is at least nothing of what you are mentioning here. Everything in your answer is just a guess, that turned out to be not the source of the problem. It still gave you two upvotes, which is all you want. But you've asked the right question in your last comment.

Comment: I edited my answer slightly to add that the properties must be set in order for any values to show up in the DataGrid.

Comment: All these edits wouldn't be necessary if you'd simply wait until OP writes a precise problem description.

Comment: @Stefan: Fair enough. I clarified this in my answer.